# Locate the most recently modified file in a folder tree and set it to a variable

Tags: batch-file

**What I need**:

-A batch script that allows me to look for any files `*.class.asasm` inside a lot of directories and sub-directories

-Pick the most recent file that has been modified/written and set it as a variable

(Not only `file.class.asasm` **but** like `F:\swf\tool\RABCDAsm\ClientLibSystem-123\extraFolder\file.class.asasm`)

-Last thing, all of my folders will be named like `ClientLibSystem-123` or ClientLibSystem-`9`

-I need to grab that number and also set it to a variable

**My script:**
http://pastebin.com/M3WkQKJD

Added below:

```
@echo off
title Auto recompile
cls
pause
:c
dir /O:D /S /A:-D >> l.l
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a IN ('find " " ^<l.l') DO SET file=%%a
```

With your help I'm going to be able to recompile ActionScript 3 Bytecode files a lot quicker !

Comment: Please edit the question title so that others can get what it is about...

Comment: Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service. I hope my answer could help you by providing some useful hints rather than giving a bullet-proof solution to satisfy your complex aim... I believe that anyone could find answer  for nearly _any_ particular subtask here at SO :)

Comment: @aschipfl Do you have access to edit other posts at this stage?  When a user gets the ability then it's appropriate to fix spelling, bad formatting, grammar, titles, all sorts of things.  I've just edited this question.

Comment: @foxidrive, yes, I have access to editing (my edits will be reviewed); however, I wanted the *questioner* (who is a new member obviously) to think of a good title; that is why I just placed a comment...

Comment: @aschipfl Understood.  Long term support has shown me that people learn gradually and eventually get up to speed - fixing flaws is a big part of SO to make it a valuable resource - and a telling point is that the OP hasn't responded (which is common, and why fixing is better done by you or I etc if you have the time).

Comment: I see, @foxidrive, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with next somewhat improved code snippet. Feel free to ask more in comment or [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32428074/edit) to add your improved code or data sample there.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
title Auto recompile
cls
:c
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('
    dir /B /O:D /S /A:-D F:\*.class.asasm ^|find /I "ClientLibSystem-"
  ') DO (
    set "file=%%a"
    rem grab that number from "!file:*ClientLibSystem-=!" as follows
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=\" %%G in ("!file:*ClientLibSystem-=!") do set "grab=%%G"
    echo found !grab! [%%~ta] "!file!"
    rem find the most recent file via comparing %%~ta
)
pause
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~ta` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`!file:*ClientLibSystem-=!`) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: That's not what I've wanted.


The problem is that your code detect all files, I need the last edited only